# jscodeshift/recast: objectExpression is always pretty-printed. How can I prevent that?

Tags: jscodeshift

I am using jscodeshift to transform function calls:

foo() --> foo({uid: ... label: ...})

```
const newArgObj = j.objectExpression([
    j.property(
        'init',
        j.identifier('uid'),
        j.literal(getUID()),
    ),
    j.property(
        'init',
        j.identifier('label'),
        j.literal('bar'),
    )
]);
node.arguments = [newArgObj];

...

return callExpressions.toSource({quote: 'single'});
```

The problem is objectExpression is always pretty-printed:

```
foo({
    uid: 'LBL_btBeZETZ',
    label: 'bar'
})
```

How to prevent that and get something like:

```
foo({uid: 'LBL_btBeZETZ', label: 'bar'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, it is impossible, take a look at [recast's printer.js source](https://github.com/benjamn/recast/blob/52a7ec3eaaa37e78436841ed8afc948033a86252/lib/printer.js#L574):

```
case "ObjectExpression":
case "ObjectPattern":
case "ObjectTypeAnnotation":
    ...
    var len = 0;
    fields.forEach(function(field) {
        len += n[field].length;
    });

    var oneLine = (isTypeAnnotation && len === 1) || len === 0;
    var parts = [oneLine ? "{" : "{\n"];
    ...
            if (!oneLine) {
                lines = lines.indent(options.tabWidth);
            }
    ...
    parts.push(oneLine ? "}" : "\n}");
```

WORKAROUND (at least in my simple case) - you can use raw string:

```
const rawCode = `{uid: '${getUID()}', label: 'bar' }`;
node.arguments = [rawCode];
```

or

```
node.arguments = [j.jsxText(rawCode)];
```

Both will give you:

```
foo({uid: 'LBL_btBeZETZ', label: "bar" })
```